# how to change url without changing browser history

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

Until now, I only know that if I want to change URL without reloading the whole page i have to use HTML browser [history](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html) API.

I am using this concept in my website. Let's take example. Let suppose user is on this page

```
 https://www.example.com/aboutus
```

and then he goes to product listing in which we have filters.  On clicking any filters system generates new url something like this

```
https://www.example.com/products?brands[]=song&brands[]=samsung&condition[]=new
```

Internally it is just calling

```
history.pushState({}, 'Title', link.href);
```

But, it has one problem. Clicking `back` button takes to the previous filter. **I dont want this functionality**. I want , on clicking browser back button it should take to the page which is before `current` page. In our case, it is suppose to take to

```
https://www.example.com/aboutus
```

Thanks.

Comment: well, if you are redirecting to a different page (`/products` from `/aboutus`, doesn't it reload anyway? and the whole point of the history API is to allow urls in the back menu to go to a previous state on the same page

Comment: You could also use <iframe>

Comment: FYI, the question was asked when coursera had this functionality, currently i doubt.

Comment: window.location.replace(url) will change location without adding a new entry to history, it is not bound to same origin. It will reload the page obviously

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You're looking for `replaceState()`, it replaces the current position in the history instead of pushing a new one, like `pushState()` does

```
history.replaceState({}, 'Title', link.href);
```

from [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState)

> The History.replaceState() method modifies the current history entry, replacing it with the state object and URL passed in the method parameters. This method is particularly useful when you want to update the state object or URL of the current history entry in response to some user action.

Remember, [some functions are not available on older browsers](http://caniuse.com/history). But there is a [library](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)
that could help you out.

Comment: On the same MDN page above, it also states `Note that this doesn't prevent the creation of a new entry in the global browser history.`

Comment: Question: says "without changing browser history". Solution says: "replaceState() modifies the current history entry". So how do I change the URL without changing the history? I want to open URL `test.html`, click the link to `test2.html`, click button to change to address bar to `test3.html` (without actually downloading `test3.html`), then I press "back" to go to `test.html` and when I press "forward" it must go to `test2.html`, not to `test3.html`. So how do I do this?