# Hide/show browser history back button when it can't take action

Tags: javascript, html

I want the back / forward browser history button that when they can't perform actions they become disabled and the opposite.

For example, if I can't go back the button becomes disabled:

[image]

And if I can it becomes pressable.

[image]

Comment: This is not under the control of the page you are on. What if the user was on a different page before?

Comment: My example is based on a clean site so this problem shouldn't be there. @ChristianFritz

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change url without changing browser history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937280/how-to-change-url-without-changing-browser-history)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.